# Store integers in an input, separately to characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, phone-number

Basically, I am creating a program which converts phone numbers with
letters in, into just plain numbers. I have managed to do this,
however, if you input numbers, they are removed and ONLY the converted
letters are returned.

For example, if you input `1800BUYNOW`, instead of returning `1800289669`,
it returns just `289669`.

Any help?

```
#phone number converter
#v0.8
#this will convert phone numbers with letters in, into just phone numbers
#i.e. 1800BUYNOW should output as 1800289669

import time
import string

dicti = []

#######################################################################

def translate():
    print('Welcome to the telephone unconfuzzler!')
    num = input('''Type the number you which to deconfuzzle.
''')
    for char in (num):
        if char in ['A','B','C']:
            dicti.append(2)
        if char in ['D','E','F']:
            dicti.append(3)
        if char in ['G','H','I']:
            dicti.append(4)
        if char in ['J','K','L']:
            dicti.append(5)
        if char in ['M','N','O']:
            dicti.append(6)
        if char in ['P','Q','R','S']:
            dicti.append(7)
        if char in ['T','U','V']:
            dicti.append(8)
        if char in ['W','X','Y','Z']:
            dicti.append(9)
    finish()

#######################################################################

def finish():
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('''Converting
...''')
     time.sleep(1)
     print('''Here is your deconfuzzled number:''')
     print (*dicti, sep='')
     end()

#######################################################################

def end():
    conta = input('Would you like to convert another number?')
    if conta in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:
        translate()
    elif conta in ['n', 'N', 'no', 'No', 'NO']:
        conta2 = input('Are you sure you would like to quit?')
        if conta2 in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:
            exit()
        elif conta2 in ['n', 'N', 'no', 'No', 'NO']:
            end()


#######################################################################

translate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
   if char in ['A','B','C']:
```

by

```
   if char in ['A','B','C','1']:
```

and so on.

Actually you should have an else at the end which reports unknown characters and replace the if's by elifs.

Comment: Thanks man, just a starter coder! Now I have the issue of if they answer yes to enter a new number, I need to empty the dicti list of the old ones, any help?

Comment: Actually in your current code you need to. However, it would be much cleaner if dicti is a local variable of the translate function and you return the calculated value

Comment: Any chance you can show what that would like like? I'm a real noob. I understand what global and local variables are but I'm not sure about the returning of one outside of the function it is defined in.

Comment: Don't want to steal the learning experience. Here you finde a good explanation http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html